# JPEG size made smaller by MSPAINT, why?

Tags: export, jpeg, microsoft-paint

I have lots of JPEGs from DSLR, and they are roughly about 5-6MB per JPEG. I open any of them using MSPAINT, and click the SAVE and notice the size immediately go down to 2-3MB.

Why? there seems no setting for JPEG quality in MSPAINT.

Comment: Don't use MSPaint? It's very basic and it's probably compressing the image a bit more than you would expect.

Comment: You have answered your question - lower quality.

Comment: "No setting" does not mean that it knows what setting was applied to begin with so it will use its own default. Also jpeg  is lossy, meaning that every time you open and re-save it you will be loosing quality, even if you always use the "100" setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even as you can't tweak a quality value when you save a *jpg* file in MS PAINT, it applies a default value that it's unknown (around 75% - 85%). This value will degrade the quality and reduce the size of the file.

The image file gets smaller and loses quality. If you view the image and zoom to more than 100% you can usually see the artifacts caused by the JPEG compression as in this example (a leaf in foreground and sky in the background):

[image]